# ASIOCallbacks::bufferSwitchTimeInfo comes very slowly in 2.8MHz Samplerate with DSD format on Sony PHA-3

Tags: c++, native, asio

I bought a Sony PHA-3 and try to write an app to play DSD in native mode. (I've succeeded in DoP mode.)
However, When I set the samplerate to 2.8MHz, I found the ASIOCallbacks::bufferSwitchTimeInfo come not so fast as it should be.

It'll take nearly 8 seconds to request for 2.8MHz samples which should be completed in 1 second.

The code is merely modified from the host sample of asiosdk 2.3, thus I'll post a part of the key codes to help complete my question.

After ASIO Start, the host sample will keep printing the progress to indicating the time info like this:

```
fprintf (stdout, "%d ms / %d ms / %d samples **%ds**", asioDriverInfo.sysRefTime, 
(long)(asioDriverInfo.nanoSeconds / 1000000.0), 
(long)asioDriverInfo.samples,
(long)(**asioDriverInfo.samples  / asioDriverInfo.sampleRate**));
```

The final expression will tell me how many seconds has elapsed. (asioDriverInfo.samples/asioDriverInfo.sampleRate).

Where asioDriverInfo.sampleRate is 2822400 Hz.

And asioDriverInfo.samples is assigned in the ASIOCallbacks::bufferSwitchTimeInfo like below:

```
    if (timeInfo->timeInfo.flags & kSamplePositionValid)
    asioDriverInfo.samples = ASIO64toDouble(timeInfo->timeInfo.samplePosition);
else
    asioDriverInfo.samples = 0;
```

It's the original code of the sample.

So I can easily find out the time elapsed very slowly.

I've tried to raise the samplerate to even higher, say 2.8MHz * 4, it's even longer to see the time to advance 1 second.

I tried to lower the samplerate to below 2.8MHz, the API failed.

I surely have set the SampleFormat according to the guide of the sdk.

ASIOIoFormat aif;
                memset(&aif, 0, sizeof(aif));

```
            aif.FormatType = kASIODSDFormat;

            ASIOSampleRate finalSampleRate = 176400;

            if(ASE_SUCCESS == ASIOFuture(kAsioSetIoFormat,&aif) ){
                finalSampleRate = 2822400;
            }
```

In fact, without setting the SampleFormat to DSD, setting samplerate to 2.8MHz will lead to an API failure.

Finally, I remembered all the DAW (Cubase / Reaper, ...) have an option to set the thread priority, so I doubted the thread of the callback is not high enough and also try to raise its thread priority to see if this could help. However, when I check the thread priority, it returns THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL.

```
static double processedSamples = 0;

if (processedSamples == 0)
{
    HANDLE t = GetCurrentThread();
    int p = GetThreadPriority(t); // I get THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL here

    SetThreadPriority(t, THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST); // So the priority is no need to raise anymore....(SAD)
}
```

It's same for the ThreadPriorityBoost property. It's not disabled (already boosted).

Anybody has tried to write a host asio demo and help me resolve this issue?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Issue cleared.

I should getBufferSize and createBuffers after kAsioSetIoFormat.